# Behat - Send TAB keypress

Tags: php, selenium, drupal, behat

I have a framework built with Behat, testing a drupal site, everything is built using PHP..

I need to find a hidden element on the screen, the element only appears when it is tabbed to, and the framework cannot find it by name or xpath/css... Is there any way to write a step definition that will press the tab key? I have tried, but can't get it working..

Thanks

I found this code online, and thought it would work for me -

```
  /**
 * @Given I manually press tab
 */
public function manuallyPressTab()
{
    $this->getSession()->executeScript("
$(':focus').trigger($.Event('keypress', {which: 9, keyCode: 9}));
");
```

Comment: Please provide the selenium/behat code you've tried

Comment: You need to search for jQuery scripts that will press tab and try them, some of the scripts may work for some and for some others will not.If you have a UX developer in the team i am sure he can help you.

Comment: Have you tried keyPress, keyDown or keyUp methods?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this with the following method inside a FeatureContext, and by using Zombie.js as the test runnner:

```
  /**
   * @When on :arg1 I manually press tab
   */
  public function onIManuallyPressTab($arg1) {

    $this->getSession()
      ->executeScript("jQuery('#$arg1').blur()");
  }
```

Comment: it may work in certain cases, but this is not press tab. You have also a blur method with mink. As a best practice the name of the method should describe the method functionality.